# The “outlives” relation and actual scopes

Tags: rust, lifetime

I was going through the legendary [RFC 1214](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1214-projections-lifetimes-and-wf.md) and it seems that I’m missing something crucial.

```
struct Foo;

struct Bar<'a> {
   foo: &'a Foo
}


fn f<'x, 'y>(_: &'x Foo, _: &'y Bar<'x>)
     where 'y: 'x, 'x: 'y {
}

fn g<'x>(x: &'x Foo) {
   let y = Bar {foo : x};
   f(x, &y);  // ?
}


fn main(){
   let x = Foo;
   g(&x);
}
```

In this code I went to great lengths to make sure that `'x : 'y` and **not** `'y : 'x`. The function that defines `x` calls the function that defines `y`, I believe this is already enough to guarantee that `x` outlives `y`, but I *also* put a reference to `x` inside `y`, just to make sure.

Now, the constraints in `f` are such that the invocation of this function can’t possibly be valid. I mean, well, it can, if and only if `'x == 'y`, but it totally looks like `x` lives strictly longer than `y`, as it is defined in the outer scope.

Nevertheless, this code typechecks and compiles. How is this possible?

Comment: btw: you can simplify f to take only a single lifetime parameter because you basically said that they have to be the same in the where clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lifetimes have [variance](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/subtyping.html), that is, the compiler can choose to shorten the lifetime of a `&'a Foo` to some `&'b Foo`. The lifetime of a reference like that just means that the `Foo` lasts at least as long as `'a`: a shorter lifetime still satisfies this guarantee. This is what is happening here: the `'x` lifetime is being shortened to have the same lifetime as the `&y` reference.

You can use invariance to stop this compiling: if the lifetime `'x` cannot be shortened, then the code will stop compiling as you expect.

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Foo;

struct Bar<'a> {
   foo: Cell<&'a Foo>
}


fn f<'x, 'y>(_: Cell<&'x Foo>, _: &'y Bar<'x>)
     where 'y: 'x, 'x: 'y {
}

fn g<'x>(x: Cell<&'x Foo>) {
   let y = Bar {foo : x.clone()};
   f(x, &y);  // ?
}


fn main(){
   let x = Foo;
   g(Cell::new(&x));
}
```

```txt
<anon>:16:10: 16:11 error: `y` does not live long enough
<anon>:16    f(x, &y);  // ?
                   ^
<anon>:14:28: 17:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'x as defined on the block at 14:27...
<anon>:14 fn g<'x>(x: Cell<&'x Foo>) {
<anon>:15    let y = Bar {foo : x.clone()};
<anon>:16    f(x, &y);  // ?
<anon>:17 }
<anon>:15:34: 17:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 15:33
<anon>:15    let y = Bar {foo : x.clone()};
<anon>:16    f(x, &y);  // ?
<anon>:17 }
```

What is happening here is `Cell<T>` is invariant in `T`, because it is readable and writable. This in particular means that `Cell<&'x Foo>` cannot be shortened to `Cell<&'y Foo>`: filling it with a reference `&'y Foo` that is truly `'y` (i.e. only lasts for `'y`) will mean the reference is dangling once the cell leaves `'y` (but is still in `'x`).

Answer (score 5):

Here are three things which in combination explain the behavior you see:

- The `'x` on `f` is a completely different, independent lifetime parameter from the `'x` in `g`. The compiler can choose different concrete lifetimes to substitute for each.
- `'x : 'y, 'y: 'x` means that `'x == 'y` (this is not real syntax).
- If you have a reference, you can implicitly create another reference with a *shorter* lifetime from it. Consider for example the function `fn mangle_a_string<'a>(_s: &'a str) -> &'a str { "a static string" }`

So what happens in `f(x, &y)` is that the first argument is coerced to a reference with a shorter lifetime, matching the second argument's lifetim, to satisfy the bounds in the `where` clause.